# Let $G$ be a finite group and $Z(G):=\{x\in G : gx=xg \ \ \forall g\in G\}.$ Prove that $[G:Z(G)]$ is not a prime number.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $Z(G):=\{x\in G : gx=xg \ \ \forall g\in G\}.$ Prove that $[G:Z(G)]$ is not a prime number.

I think that I should use the Lagrange Theorem, i.e.,

If $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, $$|G|=[G:Z(G)]|Z(G)|$$

So that $\dfrac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}$ cannot be a prime number.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Do not use Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Hint: show that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: It might help to know that $$G/Z(G)\cong{\rm Inn}(G),$$ where ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is the group of inner automorphisms of $G$ under composition of functions.

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/q/543735/925793 help?

Answer (score 1):

The center is always normal.   If the index is $p $ the quotient group is cyclic,  implying the group is abelian.   But then the index is one.

The key step is the

> Lemma If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.
>
> Proof: left to the reader

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $G/Z(G)$ is a prime number, let $y$ its generator (it is cyclic), write $p(x)=y$ where $p:G\rightarrow G/Z(G)$ is the quotient map, every element of $G$ can be written  $z=x^pa, a\in Z(G)$. This implies that $G$ is commutative. contradiction.